# Activiti BPM task information

Tags: spring-boot, workflow, activiti, bpmn

I'm using Activiti Workflow Engine 6.0 with Spring Boot and implemented an API for basic workflow actions.

- Start process
- Fetch tasks
- Complete a task

In order for the workflow consumer to know **which form** to display as well as **what variables** need to be set for the next exlusive gateway I'd like to deposit this information **within the task**.

Eg. If the task is called [Supervisor approval] the next gateway might decides based on a variable ${supervisorOk == true}.

To my understanding task variables are only available at runtime. Therefore I wonder what other possibilities exist to deal with task related properties / information.

Thanks in advance.